# Ajax calls (get, post) not working in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, caching

IE is driving me bananas. I've tried searching for answers on here, and the answers I've found don't seem to be working either.

I'm trying to read the output of a php file, write it within a div (that is generated using jQuery), and then check the php output every minute. I've tested the php file in all browsers, and it's working fine, so it's definitely something with the js. Here's what I've tried so far (**they work in everything BUT IE**).

The php will output:

```html
<p>Example alert text</p>
```

Right now, I have:

```js
jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: 'emerg-alert-system'
        }).prependTo( "body" ).css({
        "background": "#b40000", 
        "color": "white", 
        "display": "block", 
        "max-width": "100%", 
        "font-family": "Arial,sans-serif",
        "font-size": "1rem",
        "text-align": "center",
        "text-transform": "uppercase",
        "letter-spacing": "1px"
    });

function get_alert() {

    $.ajaxSetup( { cache: false } );

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/alert.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#emerg-alert-system").html(msg);         
    });

};

setInterval( get_alert, 1*60*1000 );

get_alert();
```

I've tried it with and without ajaxSetup/ajax cache: false, and I've also tried it with $.get() and $.post() (swapped one out for the other)

```js
function get_alert() {

    $.ajaxSetup( { cache: false } );

    $.get('http://example.com/alert.php', function(data) {
        $( "#emerg-alert-system" ).html( data );
    });

};

setInterval( get_alert(), 1*60*1000 );

get_alert();
```

The only thing generating is:

```js
<div id="emerg-alert-system"> </div>
```

Anything else I should try?

Comment: Is the request being made in IE? Can you confirm this via your Network tool in the F12 Developer Tools? Also, which version of IE are you testing against? Lastly, is this resource available online for others to access? That would help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @JonathanSampson The request isn't being made. The #emerg-alert-system div is being generated with jQuery, and that's the only thing showing up, but it's showing up empty... the generated div is the only thing I can verify is working, and it needs to work for IE 7+ (unfortunately). Lastly, only a small handful of people have read/write access to these files, but as far as I know, I'm the only one who will be touching them. Others will be able to view this alert system on the site I'm working on.

Comment: I don't see where `#emerg-alert-system` is being generated, or added to do the DOM. Also, have you checked the console (F12) for any errors or warnings when following the ajax attempt? Also, which version of jQuery are you using? With the need to support IE 7, you'll need a [1.x build of jQuery](http://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Comment: It's not part of what I included on here, but I'll edit the post showing the jQuery that generates the div, and no, there aren't any errors. I wish there were so I could have some sort of lead.

Comment: You *are* using a version of jQuery that supports IE 7, correct? Presently that would be 1.11.1 or earlier.

Comment: Yeah. They're running 1.8 on their site.

Comment: Alright. And this is not presently accessible via a public URL?

Comment: @JonathanSampson It is. Sorry, I misunderstood you before. It's being loaded onto every page of http://www.emory.edu - the js doesn't fully align with what I posted here. My co-workers and I were fumbling around with other options after I posted this.

Comment: Awesome. Having access through a live URL will make things a lot easier. I'll check it out now.

Comment: In IE 11 I see a `<p>` with `display:none`, and the text "Alert: All Clear". Are you only seeing problems in older versions of IE?

Comment: Yay! I'm glad it's working on there. I've been checking on IE9 and down.

Comment: I am also checking on IE 8, and the DOM node appears to be populated with the same text. The element itself wouldn't show until I ran `$("#emerg-alert-system p").show()` from the Script console.

Comment: The server appears to be sending back the `display: none` styling. This prevents the element from being visible in any browser; aside from this, it [appears to be working](http://i.imgur.com/zunREt0.jpg) for me in IE 7 and up.

Comment: That's music to my ears. I'm checking VMware right now.

Comment: If you don't want to wrestle with virtual machines, Microsoft is currently paying out of pocket to give you free access to http://browserstack.com via https://www.modern.ie/en-us/tools. It was the means by which I tested the legacy versions of IE. (Note: I work on the Internet Explorer team)

Comment: @JonathanSampson Awesome! Thank you so much for your help. My co-worker and I completely re-tackled this tonight, and we actually got it functioning. I'll post what we did as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my co-worker and I reworked this to no end and finally got it working to our liking. Here's the new JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: 'emerg-alert-system'
    }).prependTo( "body" ).css({
        "background": "#b40000", 
        "color": "white", 
        "display": "block", 
        "max-width": "100%", 
        "font-family": "Arial,sans-serif",
        "font-size": "1.2em",
        "text-align": "center",
        "text-transform": "uppercase",
        "letter-spacing": "1px",
        "line-height": "1.5"
    });

    function get_alert () { 
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.get('http://example.com/alert.php').done(function ( data ) {
            $("#emerg-alert-system").html(data);
            if( !$.trim( $('#emerg-alert-system').html() ).length ) {
                $("#emerg-alert-system").css({ "display": "none" });
            }
        });
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        get_alert();
        setInterval( get_alert, 1*60*1000 );
    }

});
```

Comment: @JonathanSampson what's funny is that we reworked it after what I posted to something similar to what you edited mine to (and for the most part, what I originally posted). When we ran the alert feed, it started stacking new divs on top of each other because it was being called within the "get_alert" function.

Comment: The editing I did on your answer above was merely to satisfy Stack Overflow's requirements for code here - it wasn't showing up quite right :) Is everything working properly at this point?